# Having trouble with 80% height in CSS, no solutions found so far.

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website for a gaming community. The website is supposed to be very minimalist, with the Header/Navigation covering 100%x20% of the page and the primary content covering 100%x80%. I get the divs to show up, but I cant seem to make them position themselves correctly. Due to me having to use "position:absolute;" I cant really figure out how to make these things work right. Keep in mind I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="height:100%;">
<head>
<title>ESI | Missioners and Miners Haven</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" />
</head>

<body style="height:100%;">
<div id="contianer">

<div id="navbar">

<div id="logobox">
<p>ESI Official Site</p>
</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ESI Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Corp Op's</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<div id="content">

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thats the HTML, heres the important part of the CSS:

```
#container
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#navbar
{
width:100%;
height:20%;
background:#35291F;
list-style:none;
float:left;
position:absolute;
}

#content
{
margin:10%;
width:90%;
height:80%;
background:grey;
position:absolute;
}
```

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the solutions I've found on this site worked.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You can't define the height in percent.. use pixel to define height.

Answer (score 1):

`margin:10%` will give 10% to all (top bottom right left).

give `margin-top`

and there is no need of float if position is absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a height with a `%` that I know of. You'll likely want to use `px` for this. What you should be asking yourself is, what is 100% to you? Because the height of the window is just as variable as its with. When you specify percentages in CSS, those elements contain that percentage of their parent container. You're not going to want to position those elements absolutely. You also don't need to specify the height of the `body` or `html` elements. Without seeing what exactly you're trying to accomplish visually, it's difficult to tell you what your values should be, but start there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use absolute positioning for this you need to set `top` appropriately to move `#content` down.

Couple of other things:

- Don't set styles inline (your html and body tags). Use your stylesheet.
- Why the `float` on `#navbar`? That element is already positioned `absolute`.
- The `margin` on `#content` applies to all directions (also top and bottom).

[JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/oxebac/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
#content
{
    margin-top:20%;
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    /* ... */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WJrW3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rainthinks/t23bD/1/

full screen mode: http://jsfiddle.net/rainthinks/t23bD/1/embedded/result/

```
html, body, #container {
    height:100%;
}
#navbar {
    height:20%;

    background:#35291F;
    list-style:none;
}
#content {
    height:80%;

    background:grey;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem at all; in fact it brought me back to the original problem of not being able to make the div's appear. Thanks for trying, but even when I run this code in jsfiddle.net it doesn't work properly.

Comment: the key point of assign height to a node in percentage is that, make sure its parent node have a fix height.